# android onMarkerClick doesn't call after InfoWindow hiding in GoogleMap Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, dictionary, google-maps-markers

I integrate Google Maps Android API v2 into my app and have strange behavior with markers in GoogleMap.
OnMarkerClickListener#onMarkerClick(Marker marker) is not called after InfoWindow hiding. It doesn't depend on how I show InfoWindow (neither **marker.showInfoWindow()** nor

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
.....
return true;}
```

doesn't work.
After i change camera position by touching or change zoom it  works one time. 
The same behavior I saw in GoogleMapDemo.

Here is my code

```
    private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.map_address_activity);
    setUpMapIfNeeded(); // from oficial sample

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            mMap.clear();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Marker"));
            final CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(point).zoom(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom).build();

            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        });
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
        Log.e("TESTING", "on Marker click: " + marker.getTitle());
            if (!marker.isInfoWindowShown())
                marker.showInfoWindow();
            else 
                marker.hideInfoWindow();

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Can you help me to handle click events on marker after hiding InfoWindow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what that's supposed to happen! onMarkerClick will be called only when click on marker but not when infoWindow hides.

If you want to listen for InfoWindows hide event you must implement your own logic either in onMarkerClick methode where you hideInfoWindow or in overrided onMapClick methode (because info could be hided clicking anywhere on map). In last case you must keep reference on last marker with activated infoWindow and check that window status to implement you logic.